# VBA Generate Random Number to 3 decimal places

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA I need to randomly generate numbers between 0 and 1 to 3 decimal places ex. 0.564

This works:

```
x = rnd
x = round(x,3)
```

but this does not, it yields many more decimals

```
x = round(rnd, 3)
```

why does it work in 2 steps but not one?

Comment: How many more? What is the type of x? If I remenber the function VBA Round uses Banker rounding. It could maybe the reason. Do you have the same result if you use the Worksheet Round Function?

Comment: On my machine, both methods work. Are you that the second one isn't working? If so, what application are you using to run your VBA macro? I'm testing with Excel 2010.

Comment: Consider marking ***Andre's*** solution as ***Answer***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Rnd function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns a random number of type **Single**.

Assigning this to a Double variable leaves the "higher precision" bits undefined.
Your first example works, because you round **after** the assignment.

```
Sub TestRnd()

    Dim dbl As Double
    Dim v As Variant

    dbl = Rnd
    Debug.Print dbl
    dbl = Round(dbl, 3)
    Debug.Print dbl

    dbl = Round(Rnd, 3)
    Debug.Print dbl

    v = Rnd
    Debug.Print v
    v = Round(v, 3)
    Debug.Print v

    v = Round(Rnd, 3)
    Debug.Print v

End Sub
```

-->

```
 0,862619340419769 
 0,863 

 0,790000021457672 

 0,3735362 
 0,374 

 0,054
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using Excel 2007 on a Win 7 machine and I cannot replicate your results.  If I run:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    x = Rnd()
    x = Round(x, 3)
    y = Round(Rnd(), 3)
    MsgBox x & vbCrLf & y
End Sub
```

I always get something like:

[image]

With 3 or fewer places.  If you use values like these, you may get slightly imprecise results because of the way Excel represents floating point numbers.

Comment: it looks like its happening because I had declared my variable as a double, if I don't declare it works and I get the 3 decimals. Why would this cause the change?

Comment: @ErikRasmussen  By declaring it as `Double`, you may be forcing an imprecise representation.

Comment: @ErikRasmussen: The [Rnd function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7s023d2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) returns a random number of type **Single**. Assigning this to a Double variable leaves the "higher precision" bits undefined. Your first example works, because you round **after** the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It may because when the number 0.070 will be displayed as 0.07. Also it will not show more decimal places since we have used round function.

If you take the value in a cell and format it as number with 3 decimal places you will see the result as you want.

You can also get the result with below line

```
Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 999) / 1000, 3)
```